# How do I remove the requirement for "elevation" on a program that I accidentally enabled it on?

Tags: windows, windows-10, uac

I've been having trouble finding a way to remove the requirement for elevation on an operation [740] (my PC Game--RuneScape). I believe I accidentally clicked on something and it caused it to change from not requiring admin rights to run, to now requiring it to.

Many thanks to anyone that knows how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to see if the option has been selected on the compatibility tab.

Right click on the shortcut and click "Properties". The click the compatibility tab and uncheck `Run this program as an administrator`:

[image: properties box]